# Rete.js do not render editor until window is resized

Tags: angular, rete

I'm using `Angular 7.1.4` and `"rete": "^1.4.4"`. If I use editor inside components it renders ok, but if pass editor as child to another components with ng-content it does not render Nodes inside editor until window is resized. As a workaround I tried to trigger window resize in ngOnInit:

```
setTimeout(() => {
            window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
        });
```

and it renders nodes but do not render connection lines

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix. I was initializing container in ngAfterViewInit and found out that not all style properties are attached after ngAfterViewInit event. So the fix was to set timeout

```
setTimeout(() => { const container = this.el.nativeElement; let editor = new NodeEditor("rivetNodeEditor@0.1.0", container); ... }, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the examples that come with rete https://codepen.io/Ni55aN/pen/xzgQYq you can see that you can solve the problem also with calling manually resize and process at the end of your NodeEditor setup:

```js
let editor = new NodeEditor("rivetNodeEditor@0.1.0", container)
... //Setting up node components
editor.view.resize()
editor.trigger('process')
```